# How to put braces in django templates?

Tags: django, braces

I need to produce an id surrounded by braces ( for example "{1234}" ). With the django template language, braces are also used to start a variable substitution, so I have some trouble in obtaining what I want. I tried

```
{{{ id }}}
{{ '{'id'}' }}
{{ '{'+id+'}' }}
{ {{ id }} }
```

None of these methods work, except the last one, which unfortunately produces "{ 1234 }", not what I want. I currently have two solutions : either I pass an id variable already containing the {} (ugly) or I write a custom filter and then write {{ id|add_braces }} (I prefer it).

Before going this way, I prefer to ask if a better solution exists.

Using escaped values does not work. Even if I add {% autoescape off %}%7B{% endautoescape %} I don't get the {, which is strange, but that's another problem.

Thanks

**Edit**: I wrote a quick filter. Pasting it here so someone else can use it as a template for writing a more complex one. To be put into python package application_path/templatetags/formatting.py

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def add_braces(value):
    return "{"+value+"}"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think your answer can be found here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag

In short, you want to use `{% templatetag openbrace %}` and `{% templatetag closebrace %}`.

Edit:
Django now also includes this functionality out of the box:

```
{% verbatim %} {{ blah blah }} {% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: Thanks! in any case I wrote a filter. Adding it so if someone wants to use it as a small filter example...

Answer (score 10):

`{% templatetag openbrace %}` become extremely verbose for e.g. javascript templates

I've used the `verbatim` tag from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1313862) with some success for exactly this purpose which lets you do something like

```
{{ request.user }}
{% verbatim %}
     brackets inside here are left alone, which is handy for e.g. jquery templates
     {{ this will be left }}
     {% so will this %}
{% endverbatim }}

{% more regular tags (to be replaced by the django template engine %}
```

Comment: the verbatim template tag is now part of django (1.5): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim

Comment: The accepted answer on this question should probably be changed - verbatim really is the right way to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation from the Jinja templating language works with the Django templating engine as well:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping

The solution is this:

```
{{ '{' }}{{ id }}{{ '}' }}
```

Of course the other two answers work, but this is one is less verbose and more readable, in my opinion.

Comment: For small verbatim values, this is a good solution. For large blocks, I'd go with the `{% verbatim %}` block tag.