# literal {{something}} in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put braces in django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659492/how-to-put-braces-in-django-templates)

How do I write {{ something }} without it getting parsed by django template system. I am trying to make addthis templates work, and they use the same {{..}}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{% templatetag openvariable %} something {% templatetag closevariable %}`