# How to write "{{" or "{%" itself in Django template?

Tags: django, templates, escaping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put braces in django templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659492/how-to-put-braces-in-django-templates)

When I use jQuery template I need to use {{ in my HTML. It is variable delimiter in Django templates. How to escape it so that Django template system won't react on it and have {{ in resulting HTML?

UPD: this is documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag

Comment: the templatetag option is so verbose it becomes silly when trying to write e.g. jquery templates. for such situations something like the `verbatim` gist are far superior in my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've used the `verbatim` tag from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1313862) with some succes for exactly this purpose

Comment: verbatim is better then templatetag for this purpose, thanks!