# Escaping other things that also enclose their own vars in {{ }}

Tags: django, addthis

I am using the "AddThis" widget for sharing pages and such for a site, you're able to customize the output of it by including some JS and making it as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_share = {
  templates: { twitter: {{ title }} : example {{ url }} RT @exampleuser' }
}
</script>
```

the {{ title }} and {{ url }} is AddThis' way of getting the title and url set for their service but this syntax is also Django's variable syntax, does anyone know how I can use this properly? Django is trying to read this variables when the page is loading, I  want to avoid this and make it so the url and title is AddThis' data instead.

Thx

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8358919/105043

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put braces in django templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659492/how-to-put-braces-in-django-templates)

Answer (score 0):

I know precisely f***all about django, but when I have JS syntax conflicts with other server-side frameworks, putting the offending code in its own .js file usually fixes it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could do what the more knowledgeable people in the comments told you to do. You know, something that might actually work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to escape {{ }} in a template. Alternate way is to make a separate file containing AddThis.html file and include it in your template like this:

```
{% ssi /home/html/AddThis.html %}
```

ssi template tag does not parse the variables